# PHP : whats error on there

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It shows an error as shown below when im run it on web..

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\trial\checkadd.php on line 30"

I don't know whats error on there..

Im using `phpmyadmin` to store on database but the image can't on web..i dont know the error from php or sql..pls help me to find it..i also add my php coding that show error here..pls have a look..thanks in advance

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="MMDB"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="artist"; // Table name 

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Name=$_POST['Name']; 
$Hometown=$_POST['Hometown']; 
$Income=$_POST['Income'];
$Image=$_POST['Image'];

//$file   =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$Video=$_POST['Video']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Name, Hometown, Income, Image, Video)
VALUES ('$Name', '$Hometown', '$Income', 'Image','$Video')";
$sql = "(SELECT $tbl_name FROM artist WHERE id=file)" ;

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)); {

    include 'admin.php';
} else {
    echo "x";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax error:**

No semi-colon after `(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));`

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    include 'admin.php';
} else {
    echo "x";
}
```

Comment: but its still shows error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmptySite\checkadd.php on line 29

Comment: Nope. When I remove the semicolon it shows no syntax error anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Second oldest gotcha.

> ```
> if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)); {
> ```

See that semicolon? That terminates the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql));
```

Actually it end the line immediate after the semicolon (;) and the rest of the part of if will be taken as different code where **else** is present without **if** as it end already at that same line.

So modified code should be :

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    include 'admin.php';
} else {
    echo "x";
}
```

Comment: No offense, but what exactly is the difference between what you said 20 minutes ago, to what Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and myself answered 3hrs ago when the question was first posed? You just mixed what I answered with what Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answered...

Comment: Yes Rasclatt You have given the answer I saw it after I posted the answer. Hope that will be ok too. And I have added the explanation.